# Creating an many-to-many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three models as follows:

```py
users_projects = db.Table('users_projects',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer,
              db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('project_id', db.Integer,
              db.ForeignKey('project.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    projects = db.relationship('Project', secondary=users_projects , lazy='dynamic',
                               back_populates='users')
    tasks = # What should I put here?

class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

    users = db.relationship('User', secondary=users_projects , lazy='dynamic',
                               back_populates='projects')
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='project', lazy='dynamic')

class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'), nullable=False)
```

I would like to be able to get all of users tasks such that I could do `User.query.first().tasks.order_by(Task.due_date.desc())` which would require a many-to-many-to-many relationship. How would I create such a relationship? Is this better way of handling this query?

Comment: The answer to "how would I create such a relationship?" seems to be [in the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many).

Comment: That creates a many to many, which I use between the User and Project model. I want to create a many-to-many-to-many such that from the User I can get all tasks as a query object